# How Disable Browser Back Button only after 1 minits

Tags: wordpress

How Disable Browser Back Button only after 1 minits

```
 <script type = "text/javascript" >
    function preventBack() { window.history.forward(1); }
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload = function () { null };
```

It deactivates completely
I just want to disable go back for a minute
example: https://www.arabpage.net/

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You can combine `addEventListener` on `load` with the `onbeforeunload`. And then we delay it with a `setTimeout`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener( "load", function() {
  setTimeout( function() {
    return;
  }, 10000 ); // ... 10000ms = 10s, 60 000ms = 1min
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return ""; }
} );
</script>
```

---

### Edit

As per your comments.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function DisableBackButton() {
    window.history.forward()
  }
  DisableBackButton();
  window.onload = DisableBackButton;
  window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) DisableBackButton() }
  window.onunload = function() { void (3) }
</script>
```

---

### Learn more

- `onbeforeunload` @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload
- `load` @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as intended

Comment: Do you mean sending back the user to the same page ?